# Responsive layout code order

Tags: layout, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a simple layout like so

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/col-1.html

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kvj/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">
      <title>Title of the document</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
             <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        html, body{
          background:#eee;
          height:100%;

        }
        h1{
          font-family:sans-serif;
          color:#ddd;
        }
        #wrapper{
          min-height:100%;
          max-width:1000px;
          margin:0 auto;
          background:#fff;
          overflow:auto;
          border-left:30px solid #eee;
          border-right:30px solid #eee;
          padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
        }
        #leftCol{
          background:yellow;
          height:200px;
          width:280px;
          float:left;
        }
        #rightCol{
          background:red;
          height:200px;
          margin-left:320px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:700px){
          #leftCol{
            float:none;
          }
          #rightCol{
            float:none;
            margin:20px 0 0 0;
          }
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>

      <div id="wrapper">


        <div id="leftCol">

          <h1>Left Col</h1>

        </div><!-- #leftCol -->


        <div id="rightCol">
          <h1>Right Col</h1>

        </div><!-- #rightCol -->


      </div><!-- #wrapper -->





      <!--jQuery -->


    </body>

    </html>
```

It's fixed width left column and fluid right column

When the window is resized i would like the left col to drop below the right col - In this example it doesn't

I know this is because the code order.

If I put the left col below the right col when the window resizes it drops below as I would like.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/col-2.html

http://jsfiddle.net/x8bKD/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">
      <title>Title of the document</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
             <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        html, body{
          background:#eee;
          height:100%;
        }
        h1{
          font-family:sans-serif;
          color:#ddd;
        }
        #wrapper{
          min-height:100%;
          max-width:1000px;
          margin:0 auto;
          background:#fff;
          overflow:auto;
          border-left:30px solid #eee;
          border-right:30px solid #eee;
          padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
        }


        #leftCol{
          background:yellow;
          height:200px;
          width:280px;
          float:left;

        }
        #rightCol{
          background:red;
          height:200px;
          float:right;
        }


        @media only screen and (max-width:700px){
          #leftCol{
            float:none;
          }
          #rightCol{
            float:none;
            margin:0 0 20px 0;
          }
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>

      <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="rightCol">
          <h1>Right Col</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="leftCol">

          <h1>Left Col</h1>

        </div>


      </div><!-- #wrapper -->




    </body>

    </html>
```

My problem now Is how do I make the right col stretch so it fills the space.

### Negative Margins

I know I can do this with negative margins like so

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/col-3.html

http://jsfiddle.net/vkZPj/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="robots" content="">
      <title>Title of the document</title>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
             <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        html, body{
          background:#eee;
          height:100%;
        }
        h1{
          font-family:sans-serif;
          color:#ddd;
        }
        #wrapper{
          min-height:100%;
          max-width:1000px;
          margin:0 auto;
          background:#fff;
          overflow:auto;
          border-left:30px solid #eee;
          border-right:30px solid #eee;
          padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
        }


        #leftCol{
          background:yellow;
          height:200px;
          width:280px;
          float:left;

        }
        #rightCol{
          background:red;
          height:200px;
          width:100%;
          margin-left:-290px;
          float:right;
        }
        #rightCol-inner{

          margin-left:290px;
        }    

        @media only screen and (max-width:700px){
          #leftCol{
            float:none;
          }
          #rightCol{
            float:none;
            margin:0 0 20px 0;
          }
          #rightCol-inner{

            margin-left:0;
          }
        }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>

      <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="rightCol">
          <div id="rightCol-inner">
             <h1>Right Col</h1>
          </div><!-- #rightCol-inner -->

        </div>

        <div id="leftCol">

          <h1>Left Col</h1>

        </div>


      </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Is the negative margin the only way - it would add a ton of div's to my code

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.  I tried getting your CSS out of your master.css file but there was nothing there.  Try creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Lowkase, I have updated with code and jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Having a hard time understanding it just what you want with all of the examples you listed, but....

Order your div's this way:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftCol">
        <h1>Left Col</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol">
        <h1>Right Col</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Put an overflow:hidden in #wrapper:

```
#wrapper{
  min-height:100%;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:hiddeen;
  border-left:30px solid #eee;
  border-right:30px solid #eee;
  padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Float both columns to the left, give the right column a max-width:

```
#leftCol{
  background:yellow;
  height:200px;
  width:280px;
  float:left;

}
#rightCol{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  max-width:500px;
  float:left;
}
```

If you want to see the right column stretch you need to put some content in it (e.g. - lorum ipsum).

Comment: I had to add the code to add the jsfiddle - if I have the leftCol first it will appear above the rightCol when the window is resized.

Comment: Lowkase, here is your code http://jsfiddle.net/sfJ5G/2/ - I have renamed the rightCol to Content(I think thats easier to understand). When the window is resized I need the content to be on top.

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  Do you want the left col to "snap" down and the right col to "snap" left when the width of the container is reduced to the point that it can't hold the left and right cols?  Going back to what you had, right-col float:right and ordering the cols so that the right-col comes out on top was the right way to do, unless you want the cols to "snap" into position.